# How to use back camera instead of the front camera?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, camera

I have a QR scanning camera, but when I open my website on a cell phone, the face camera turns on in my website. I want to use the back camera.

```
function setwebcam()
{

 var constraints = { audio: true, video: true };




document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="- scanning -";
if(stype==1)
{
    setTimeout(captureToCanvas, 500);    
    return;
}
var n=navigator;
document.getElementById("outdiv").innerHTML = vidhtml;
v=document.getElementById("v");

if(n.getUserMedia)
    n.getUserMedia(constraints, success, error);
else
if(n.webkitGetUserMedia)
{
    webkit=true;
    n.webkitGetUserMedia(constraints, success, error);
}
else
if(n.mozGetUserMedia)
{
    moz=true;
    n.mozGetUserMedia(constraints, success, error);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to force the device to use front camera you can add [facingMode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaTrackConstraints/facingMode) in constraints:

```js
var constraints = { 
  audio: true,
  video: {
    facingMode: 'environment'
};
```

or use `exact`:

```
facingMode: { exact: 'environment' }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `MediaStreamTrack.getSources(callback)` to get all media sources and their id's. With other properties you can filter to check is it audio video or filter by name. Once you know id of media source you want to show, use it to attach it to video tag.

This is good example:
https://simpl.info/getusermedia/sources/
https://github.com/samdutton/simpl/blob/master/getusermedia/sources/js/main.js

Comment: i tray  to chang my cod  i read all the codes from this link but  everythink what i do its wrong

Comment: how can i start  when i open a page the back camera and not a front camera?? pleas help me

Comment: Your chance is only to know name or part of name that identifies back camera, since each MediaTrack from get user media function contains name, and match it by name. You may also use resolution constraints but this is no guarantee that it is back camera.

Answer (score 0):

If the previous examples did not work for you, try this other way:

```js
Webcam.set({
 width: 250,
 height: 200,
 image_format: 'jpeg',
 jpeg_quality: 90,
 // I add this object constraints
 constraints: {
   facingMode: 'environment'
 }
});
```